# Hi am trying to pass my movieprices array from checkbox values to another function that calculates the total of the selections but my code doesn't run

Tags: javascript, arrays

Am trying to define a certain function here to calculate the total
    var total =0;
    var movie_prices = [];// create the movie prices array but it is waiting for values from user selections like 14,16,35//
    function calculateTotal(arguments){ //this is the called function//

```
 var len = arguments.length
 for(vari=0; i<len;i++){
total+= parseInt(arguments[i]); return total;
}
}

This function will display the total by determining which movies are checked;
function displayTotal(){ 

  var obj = document.getElementById('flicks'); //flicks is an id to the table element containing checkboxes//
  var top = obj.getElementByTagName('input');// reference to checkboxes of input type//
  var leng = top.length;
  for(vari=0; i< leng;i++){
    if(top[i].checked ){

     movie_prices.push(top[i].value;);

    }
  }

  call to the calculateTotal function with movieprices array as an argument;

    calculateTotal(movie_prices);

    window.alert("The total amount you now owe is:" + total); // display total//
}
```

Comment: please anyone help am stuck for days. This is my jfiddle codehttps://jsfiddle.net/kimsy06/89ve9dke/17/

Comment: What's the problem? "My code doesn't run" is too unspecific. Error message? Results differing from expected results?

Comment: Am trying to display the total in an alert message but nothing comes up

Comment: The variable `total` in the last line of your code is undefined and therefore doesn't contain any meaningful value. Note that it has nothing to do with the `return total` in line 3, as this appears to be the body of another function. It's difficult to see what's going on from your code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see so far.  Line seven should be a comment so if you don't have it commented out at runtime that would be giving you errors.

Also the method top[i].value appears to be undefined.  Where have you declared value in your code?

Comment: i have declared the value in my html code for each checkbox like ;     <input type="checkbox" name="ai" value="1500"> in this checkbox it is 1500.

Comment: also line 7 is commented out at run time.